Single value lat/lons from CDS API when selecting doing sub-region extraction
When I do the sub-region extraction from the CDS API, my netCDF file does not contain the subregion values, it only contains values for 1 data point (the NW corner of my bounding box).
My request is as follows:
c.retrieve(
'reanalysis-era5-single-levels',
{
    'product_type': 'reanalysis',
    'variable': 'surface_solar_radiation_downwards',
    'year': '2004',
    'month': '01',
    'day': [
        '01', '02', '03',
        '04', '05', '06',
        '07', '08', '09',
        '10', '11', '12',
        '13', '14', '15',
        '16', '17', '18',
        '19', '20', '21',
        '22', '23', '24',
        '25', '26', '27',
        '28', '29', '30',
        '31',
    ],
    'time': [
        '00:00', '01:00', '02:00',
        '03:00', '04:00', '05:00',
        '06:00', '07:00', '08:00',
        '09:00', '10:00', '11:00',
        '12:00', '13:00', '14:00',
        '15:00', '16:00', '17:00',
        '18:00', '19:00', '20:00',
        '21:00', '22:00', '23:00',
    ],
    'area': [
        40.5, -3.7, 40.4,
        -3.6,
    ],
    'format': 'netcdf',
},
'download.nc')

When I open the dataset with Panoply, I get the following:

The latitude and longitude do not appear as a 1D type (which I get if I do not use the sub-region extraction).
When I investigate further, I see my latitude/longitude is a float32 array size (1,0).
longitude = data['longitude'].values
print(longitude)

latitude = data['latitude'].values
print(latitude) 

This returns [-3.7] and [40.4], respectively. The same holds true if I do data['latitude'][:].values or if I add .flatten() after values.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue? I would like to see the data for both data points of my bounding box (my colleague who manually downloaded data 5 years ago has data for both data points).
